# Why is only the last value of the array being displayed by my for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-mobile, for-loop

When I use this for loop, it only outputs the last value of my array. Why if this so?

```
fouteAntwoorden = [];
for (i = 0; i < fouteAntwoorden.length; i++) { 
        document.getElementById('antwoorden').innerHTML = fouteAntwoorden[i] + '<br>';      
    }
```

If you want to see my whole project, see the JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/yTZbP/1/

EDIT:

With my app you have to assign words to dativ or accusativ. If it's wrong, I want the words which you had wrong displayed on the result_page. But my for loop only displays the last wrong answer. Can you help?

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
document.getElementById('antwoorden').innerHTML = fouteAntwoorden[i] + '<br>';
```

reassigns the contents of the `antwoorden` tag upon every iteration. Perhaps you meant `+=`:

```
document.getElementById('antwoorden').innerHTML += fouteAntwoorden[i] + '<br>';
```

If you'd like to have multiple elements with separate words inside, why don't you just create individual elements for storing the text?

```
for (i = 0; i < fouteAntwoorden.length; i++) {
    p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = fouteAntwoorden[i] + '<br>';
    document.getElementById("SomeContainer").appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: It kind of works. I get more values displayed. But the output is kinda odd with `+=`

Comment: Perhaps if you told us why or how it is wrong, we could help more.

Comment: Still not completely clear; I have an idea about what you might be asking for, but don't take me wrong if I'm not right, I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: Please check your solution before you post it. Just to check, set the slider to 10 and click 10 times one of the three buttons. Then you have some words good and some wrong. Both of your answers give the wrong words, but in a really odd order and multiple times too. I hope you could help me further..

Comment: @user1761155 I think if there's somebody who can ask the other to check something, then it's me, not you. You have made a quite obvious mistake for which my solution is good - if it still doesn't work, the only reason for that is that you have some more errors in the code at different places.